# ¿Se puede introducir nulls dentro de un String?

Tags: java, string

Me gustaría saber si existe alguna forma de, dentro de un String, encontrar un elemento null o otro elemento que me sirva como una especie de chivato para que, si por ejemplo trato char por char todos los Caracteres de la cadena, me sirva para distinguir si debo tratar el siguiente caracter de una forma o de otra.

Así explicado suena un poco raro pero pondré un ejemplo muy sencillo:

Tengo un String que contiene una serie de números y, por el motivo que sea, quiero tratar algunos como char y otros como int y que haya un elemento (que no sea ningun caracter o algo interpretable como caracter) que me permita distinguir antes si tratarlo como número o char.

No sé si acabo de explicarme. Si sirve para explicar el contexto, estoy haciendo la descodifciación en LZ78 y quiero distinguir el indice del diccionario si tiene más de un digito o el digito es el caracter que hay que descodificar.

Comment: mmm.. pero un nulo es un char ;) es tan char como una A o un 0 o $ o ? o ~...

Comment: No es que seas muy claro en tu pregunta. Pero, me pregunto si no sería mejor comprobar si el carácter que quieres examinar es numérico por ejemplo ¿?

Comment: podrías hacer un ArrayList de caracteres (Character) y ahí si podes guardar nulos, pero ya no sería un String, aunque lo podes pasar a String con un método